# google oauth not redirect properly

Tags: google-oauth

I am working on site where I have used google OAuth 2.0. when I click on login link on my index page, it takes me to the login page of the google ( all required credentials with clien_id, key, redirect url has been passed with the link) and after entering credentials,  it ask for granting access to the app. when I click on grant access instead of redirecting to my redirect page it shows me following error.

```
You've reached this page because we have detected that Javascript is disabled in your browser. The page you attempted to load cannot display properly if scripts are disabled.

Please enable scripts and retry the operation or go back in your browser.
```

but in my all browsers javascript is enabled and working fine. what should I do now ?

Answer (score 0):

I can probably help you figure it out. If the "granting access" page loads and doesn't give you the JS error, but you get it after submitting the form on the page, then there is something strange with your browser and it's not submitting the form correctly.

Can you tell me what browser you can reproduce this on? And if possible can you give the headers and post body of your request after you submit the form?

Comment: thanks david for your help, but today morning I talk with my server admin and he told me its due to firewall of our network, page was not loaded properly. sincere apology to everyone who has tried to help me. I will take care in future before posting the question. but it was really frustrating for me

Answer (score 0):

Getting that error when the gstatic.com domain isn't enabled in the noscript addon for firefox.